# How insert a map from ArcGIS into a div using the Leaflet plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, arcgis

I have a application on ionic that is working with views, in a view a want to insert a map in a div, but is not possible for the body css declaration, I want to now if exists a wrapper to show this maps or if I need a correct the css.

Ionic view

```
<ion-view view-title="Map" can-swipe-back="false" hide-back-button="false">
  <h1>Map view</h1>
  <button ng-click="map.reloadState()" class="button positive-button">Change State!!!</button>
<\ion-view>
```

Map example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- Load Esri Leaflet locally, after cloning this repository -->
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

<style>
  html, body, #map {
    margin:0; padding:0;  width : 100%; height : 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([45.528, -122.680], 13);

  L.esri.basemapLayer("Gray").addTo(map);

  var parks = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: "http://services.arcgis.com/rOo16HdIMeOBI4Mb/arcgis/rest/services/Portland_Parks/FeatureServer/0",
    style: function () {
      return { color: "#70ca49", weight: 2 };
    }
  }).addTo(map);

  var popupTemplate = "<h3>{NAME}</h3>{ACRES} Acres<br><small>Property ID: {PROPERTYID}<small>";

  parks.bindPopup(function(e){
    return L.Util.template(popupTemplate, e.feature.properties)
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you find a solution to your problem?